# L'Hopital's rule - limit of $\dfrac{\tan{x}-x}{x- \sin x}$

Tags: limits

$$\dfrac{\tan{x}-x}{x- \sin x}$$

What's the limit as x->0? I've been working on it for ages and I'm not getting the answer which is two. The first time I used the rule: $\dfrac{\sec^2{x}-1}{1-\cos(x)}$

What am I supposed to get the second time? (Assuming first time is right)

Comment: What do you think you get on a second application?

Comment: I got something like $\dfrac{2\sec x \tan x}{\cot x}$?? (Not sure if I've done my algebra right with the fractions... tan x still remains so that's 0, meaning I don't get 2.

Comment: Derivative of $\sec^2$ is $2\sec.\sec\tan$, derivative of $1 - \cos$ is $\sin$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $\displaystyle\frac{\sec^{2}x-1}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x(1-\cos x)}=\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos^2x}\to 2$

Comment: How did you get from the middle to the RHS?

Comment: $(1-\cos^2x)=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just derivate
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan{x}-x}{x- \sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^2x}{1-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\tan x(1+\tan^2x)}{\sin x}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the given term in the form $\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\tan \left(x\right)-x}{x-\sin \left(x\right)}\right)
& = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o\left(x^3\right)\right)-x}{x-\:\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o\left(x^3\right)\right)}\right)
\\& = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x^3}{3}+o\left(x^3\right)}{\frac{x^3}{3!}+o\left(x^3\right)}\right)
\\& = \color{red}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Solved with Taylor expansion